# HTML5 Sectioning elements and china browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, html, conditional-comments, browser-support

I was building a project and was using HTML5 sectioning elements and HTML5 shiv/mordernizr to handle older IEs.

However while building the website, I begin to wonder about how will the china based browsers (such as 360, Maxthon etc) interpret the HTML5 sectioning elements and is it safe to use them. I read somewhere that many of these chinese browsers are <strike>somewhat</strike> also using IE trident engine so I wonder if this piece of code will be interpreted by them:

```
---IE conditional tag open---
    Load html5 shiv
---IE conditional tag close---
```

Comment: I can't speak specifically to those browsers, but in general, browsers just ignore tags they don't recognize. The big issue is when you try to style any of those new elements.

Answer (score 0):

[360 Secure Browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/360_Secure_Browser) is simply a Trident shell, so its rendering should be the same as IE's.

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxthon, Maxthon can use both Trident and Webkit, so its rendering should be the same as IE or Chromium depending on the engine.